# Pronunciation of the prefix "anti" in American English

Tags: pronunciation, american-english, prefixes

From what I understand, the British pronunciation would be `[anti]` pretty much everywhere. But in American English I usually hear `[antai]`, although it is mixed up with `[anti]` from time to time.

> antivirus [[anti]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Y518F6VVR4w#t=58) and [[antai]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=C2E6KcH3g30#t=32)

Is there any good rule/reason to use one versus the other?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a rule. I've heard native-born Americans from various regions and of various socioeconomic backgrounds pronouncing *antibodies*, *anti-hero*, *anti-immigration*, *antimatter*, and  *antiabortion* both ways. I'm not even consistent myself; I say *antichrist* with the "short" *i*, but *anti-Christian* with the "long."

Comment: @choster I'm American, and I pronounce "antibodies" with an "ih" sound, but all those others with "ai". Perhaps because "antibodies" seems like one whole word to me, whereas the rest seem to clearly be other worse with "anti" as a prefix? I'm not sure. But (at least where I'm from) no one says "ee" (that I can think of).

Comment: Thank you all, now I have a bit more ideas why it is like this:)

Comment: Semi is also treated this way. Semi-final.

Comment: dmi3y, you're right. British pronunciation of anti is with the *i* sound in the words *bin*, *dip* and *hit*. The other pronunciation with the *i* sound in the words *bicycle*, *dive* and *hike* is American, not British.

Comment: The answer is right in front of y'all. If there is a hiphen it's ai if not its i

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The prefix "anti" is acceptably pronounced both ways, however it is usually pronounced [antai] (or to a lesser extent [anti]) when stressed or emphasized, and [antɪ] as in 'lid' when said otherwise.

Comment: What is the difference between [anti] and [antɪ]? Could you give me some examples? Thank you

Comment: @GamalThomas See [Wikipedia’s IPA vowel chart with audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio)